# Hibernate OneToOne c FetchType.JOIN

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, java-ee

Есть 2 сущности:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "page")
public class Page {
    @Id
    int id;
}
```

и

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "page_details")
public class PageDetails {
    @Id
    private int id;
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    private Page page;
}
```

При запросе всех PageDetails через JpaRepository.findAll я ожидаю получить 1 запрос вида:

```
select * from page inner join page_details on page.id = page_details.id;
```

Но вместо этого получаю 1 запрос:

```
select * from page;
```

и N запросов:

```
select * from page_details where id = ?;
```

Как это можно исправить? Версия Hibernate 5.0.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хибернейт иногда игнорирует EAGER инициализацию и всё равно использует LAZY. Лично я справляюсь с этим через JQL и FETCH JOIN.

т.е. в вашем случае надо создать новый метод в репозитрии вида:

```
@Queury("SELECT d FROM PageDetails d JOIN FETCH d.page")
List<PageDetail> selectAll();
```

В некоторых ситуациях возможно стоит использовать так же "LEFT OUTER", но это зависит от вашей ситуации, больше можно прочитать про это на [тут](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)(см. разделы ниже по списку - INNER JOIN и т.д.)

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что это является недокументированным поведением hibernate (или даже багом) или все-таки так и было задумано?

Comment: Как я понимаю это особенности спецификации JPA. Тут: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/463349/jpa-eager-fetch-does-not-join можно прочитать чуть больше. К сожаления у меня нет более подробного описания этой проблемы. Может кто-то из участников СО сможет ответить лучше.